# What permissions should I give directories if I want to make WordPress more secure?

Tags: security, permissions, filesystem

A follow up to a previous question found here [How can I lock down an old wordpress install I don't intend to update?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6109/how-can-i-lock-down-an-old-wordpress-install-i-dont-intend-to-update)

Same info still stands. WordPress install will (probably) not be updated. Never ending caching has been enabled. Database can only be read.

I thought my WordPress installation was pretty well locked down, however it seems that at some point, something was able to create a file in the theme directory of a funny looking nature (ending in eval(blah)).

I wouldn't class myself as a sysadmin type of guy, but I'm thinking that someone would know what directories I should set with particular permissions to harden my security.

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The WP-Security plugin is pretty good for this, and a few other wordpress security related things, it is my solution to lock down basics on security for every wordpress install I do.

Answer (score 1):

There are no hard set rules for permissions because it depends on many factors.

The basic rule is: set the permissions as low as possible for the file/dir to be usable,  and you should never have to set anything at 777.